# Detect when a specific <option> is selected with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, html-select

I'd like jQuery to detect when the option with the id `trade_buy_max` is selected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("option#trade_buy_max").select(function () {
        //do something
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='type' id='type'>
    <option id='trade_buy' value='1' selected='selected'>Buy</option>
    <option id='trade_buy_max' value='1'>Buy max</option>
    <option id='trade_sell' value='2'>Sell</option>
    <option id='trade_sell_max' value='2'>Sell max</option>
</select>
```

I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This works...
Listen for the change event on the select box to fire and once it does then just pull the id attribute of the selected option.

```
$("#type").change(function(){
  var id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id");

  switch (id){
    case "trade_buy_max":
      // do something here
      break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Since my option values were unique, I could use this : var val = $('#select_xyz').val();  And the mistake I was making before I saw this post - I was using click(..) when I should have used .change(..) .  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

What you need to do is add an `onchange` handler to the `select`:

```
$('#type').change(function(){ 
  if($(this).val() == 2){
     /* Do Something */
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

you can bind `change` event on its select instead, then check if option selected

```
$("select#type").change(function () {
   if( $("option#trade_buy_max:selected").length )
   {
     // do something here
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("option#trade_buy_max").change(function () {
    opt = $(this).children("option:selected").attr('id');
    if(opt == '#trade_sell_max'){
        // do stuff
    } 
});
```

Untested, but that should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`change`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change) event and get the `id` attribute of the selected option:

```
$('#type').change(function () {
  var selectedId = $('option:selected', this).attr('id');

  if (selectedId == "trade_buy_max") {
    // do something
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change .select to .change and put space before #