# FInd if an option has been 'selected' OR 'de-selected' via change event of Select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a html multi-select select box. When i select/de-select values in a change event is fired on it.

Whats the best way to know from the event that the event is because of an element being selected or deselected? I don't want its value, just whether the change event is because of 'selection' or 'de-selection'.

Comment: Can you explain why you need it ?

Comment: I need to do an action based on whether an element has been selected or if an element has been de-selected. Like you know, show a green glow on option select, and a red glow on option de-selected. Not that im doing this exactly, but just an example.  

I could keep a count. But just wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Does this help  ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953063/detect-when-a-specific-option-is-selected-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Making a few assumptions here, you have a multi-select and you just need to know if there has been a selection or not.

Then, you just need to check the length of selected options with a cached value.

See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/2uudx/1/**

Not the most elegant or optimized way, but a direction.

```
var sel = 0;
$('#mySelect').on("change", function() {
    var newsel = $(this).find(":selected").length;
    if (newsel > sel) {
        // selected
    } else {
        if (newsel < sel) {
            // de-selected
        } else {
            // no-change
        }
    }
    sel = newsel;
});
```

If you really need to compare the values which were selected or de-selected, then instead of caching the length, you cache the selected values in an array. On *change*, compare the currently selected values to the cached array.

Hope that gives a suitable pointer.

**Update**:

Using values to compare more accurately, as mentioned above by way of arrays.

Here is a sample fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/u9XE4/3/**

```
var sel = [];
$('#s1').on("change", function() {
    var newsel = $(this).val();
    var same = compareArray(newsel, sel);
    if (same) {
        // no-change
    } else {
        if ((!same) && ((newsel.length == sel.length) || (newsel.length < sel.length))) {
            // de-selected
        } else {
            // selected
        }
    }
    sel = newsel;
});

function compareArray(a, b) {
    $.each( a, function( key, value ) {
        var index = $.inArray( value, b );
        if( index != -1 ) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

hope that helps.