# SharePoint 2010 - Handling Multiple WebCharts

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I'm designing a page in SharePoint 2010 which would have 10 WebCharts in it.

And on top of that page, I have to keep one drop down control which should allow the user to select different set of WebCharts as per the options they select.

For instance - if the user selects the Option-A, then he should be provided with first 5 charts and when he goes for Option-B, then he should be provided with next 5 charts. On the other hand, if he selects 'All' then he should be provided with all the 10 charts.

I have spent more time in searching for some relevant thread, but couldn't find the needed one. So please help in achieving this requirement.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with a bit of js and css.
it will still load all charts, but if thats okay, then you can try this.
create you ddl, capture the selection.

if you wrap your charts with a div for the first 5 and a second div for the other 5 charts you can do something like

option a

```
$('#divA').show();
$('#divA').hide();
```

option b

```
$('#divA').hide();
$('#divB').show();
```

option c

```
$('#divA').show();
$('#divA').show();
```

for capturing the change event you can easily find other posts
[Detect when a specific <option> is selected with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953063/detect-when-a-specific-option-is-selected-with-jquery)

you will also have to inject a display none into the second div, since I assume you want option a visible by default.
you can use [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) to persist the change.

good luck